# Linkedin Share with custom text is not working

Tags: socialshare

I want to share my site URL on LinkedIn with some custom text. I am using below API to post URL on LinkedIn : https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true

I can share URL but can't post custom text with URL. I tried to pass title and summary parameters but it doesn't work. Is there any other API or method to share on LinkedIn that support custom text? what would be the best approach to implement such requirements?

Comment: As far as I remember, Linkedin doesn't allow custom summary anymore. You can find similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51189486/linkedin-sharing-url-summary-not-appearing

Comment: Can you try sending your URL like this? 
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=" + your url